# Is there any function equivalent to np.unique for generic object in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, unique

[`np.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) can return indices of first occurrence, indices to reconstruct, and occurrence count. Is there any function/library that can do the same for any Python object?

Comment: You mean for any iterable python object? Or for an iterable with any python object in it?

Comment: @Yonlif For any iterable object, or at least list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as such. You can get similar functionality using different classes depending on your needs.

`unique` with no extra flags has a similar result to [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set):

```
unique_value = set(x)
```

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) simulates `return_counts`:

```
counts = collections.Counter(x)
unique_values = list(counts.keys())
unique_counts = list(counts.values())
```

To mimic `return_index`, use [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) on a `set` or `Counter`. This assumes that the container is a list

```
first_indices = [x.index(k) for k in counts]
```

To simulate `return_inverse`, we look at how `unique` is actually implemented. `unique` sorts the input to get the runs of elements. A similar technique can be acheived via [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) (or in-place [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)) and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
s = sorted(zip(x, itertools.count()))
inverse = [0] * len(x)
for i, (k, g) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(s, operator.itemgetter(0))):
    for v in g:
        inverse[v[1]] = i
```

In fact, the `groupby` approach encodes all the options:

```
s = sorted(zip(x, itertools.count()))
unique_values = []
first_indices = []
unique_counts = []
inverse = [0] * len(x)
for i, (k, g) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(s, operator.itemgetter(0))):
    unique_values.append(k)
    count = 1
    v = next(g)
    inverse[v[1]] = i
    first_indices.append(v[0])
    for v in g:
        inverse[v[1]] = i
        count += 1
    unique_counts.append(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter`:

```
> from collections import Counter

> bob = ['bob','bob','dob']
> Counter(bob)
Counter({'bob': 2, 'dob': 1})

> Counter(bob).keys()
dict_keys(['bob', 'dob'])
```

Comment: This is only a subset of the features op is looking for